# Download game with electron / detect game version with electron

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I have to build a game launcher with electron. I have two questions:

- Which way to download file from client (angularjs)? ftp? http?
- how can I detect the game version to update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With electron you can use all the APIs Node.js have additional to the APIs Chrome have.
So you can Download the game useing ftp or http like you would do in Node.js or use Ajax ($http).
For saveing you can use the normal file system, and for the version you can use the filesystem or localstorage.
Here is a snippet to save the game:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs   = require('fs');
const app  = require('remote').require('app');

var file = fs.createWriteStream(app.getDataPath() + "externalFiles/game.zip");
var request = http.get("http://dl.example.com/game.zip", response => {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

on the server you can simply have a request returning the version or the hash of the latest version, and if that changes it will download the game again.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, great i understand. One more thing, how/wich file i have to check for the hash version ? One more think how can i execute the game ? (with a cmd shell ?)

Comment: You can simply use game.zip to compute the hash, because if a file in it will change, the hash of the zip will change to. To execute the game you must [unpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) it, and then use a child process to start it

Comment: Great thanks, that's what i've thought. For optimization way, can i download only the changed file ? or i've to dl all ? If yes whit what ? :)  You help me a lot :) thanks however. One more thing how start a child process from this kind of application ? (electron ^^)

Comment: For download only changed files, its the best way is to split parts of your game in packages und download this individual packages if the hash changed, or you can use something like git (or something more lightwight), but it will not be so fast. For [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) look in the docs or search for an example

Comment: hi @julian, i come back to you because i can't go throught this, i've got lot error, response.pipe is not a function, ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'http://localhost:3100/api/getFile', and i've no idea how can i download large files like a game with module or smthg. Thanks for you help again

Comment: http.get return a stream if all works, so response.pipe should work, but if it cannot download the file. Maybe the request `localhost:3100/api/getFile` dont work. And when you like to use modules, you can pack parts of the game in extra zips, and download all changed zips

Comment: var req = request({
                  method:'GET',
                  uri: 'http://url/win'
                });
                req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(pathToTreat+'titantest'));
                req.on('data', function(chunk){
                  console.log(chunk);
                });
                req.on('error', function(err){
                  console.log('------°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°° ERROR', err);
                });
                req.end('end', function(){
                  console.log(' end ');
                });

Comment: That's the code i use to download the game but i can't dl all files from this folder only i saw the server with all files, any idea ?

Comment: First download a json with all the filenames and metadata, and the download all files you need (take a look at `Promise.all()` for that)

Comment: Ok i took a look into promise.all(), there is a module to readdir all files and automatic create the new folder to dl it ? It's not better to zpi all and unzip in front ? thanks for all @julian

Comment: Promise.all() would only be good when you want to download multiple files at once. Of course you can zip all the files into one big file and download that. But if you change only one thing, the whole game must be downloaded again, instead of only the changed part

Comment: Ok i understand, but i get an error (ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir) when i want to readdir into my path to the remote server wich contains all files. I want to do that because i don't want to list all the files for each differents extensions (7 games), and if i zip it i just have i fem files (3 to update)

Comment: Here my correct questions : 1) readdir from http://domain.com/game/extension1  2) get an files array like that i can write on the laptop 3) warning : i have files and sub-folders      Sorry but i never impleted thing like this i understand the logical but can't go throw it in my code..

Comment: you can only access the filesystem of your system. You could use a recursive readdir or walk on the server, filter the files you need and send it back and the download the files. But for simplicity create zips for each platform (if it is platform dependent) and download these and unzip on the client. If you use `unzip` you can pipe the `response` like this `response.pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'your/path' }))`.

Comment: Thanks very much @julian, one more question if i can, how can i calculate the download speed ? :)

Comment: There is a `Content-length` field in the Header. With that and how much was already downloaded you get the progress. But there are already modules like `request-progress` you can use giving the remaining time and Speed in a easy way

Comment: Thanks for all you help ! you don't made my day but my week :) , if you are in france i'll offer you a beer ^^ It's only download at 1,21 MB is it from electron kind of http limiter or the remote server connexion is bad ?

Comment: if you are in france i'll offer you a beer ^^ It's only download at 1,21 MB is it from electron kind of http limiter or the remote server connexion is bad ? And i thought about a new problem now : What can i have to do if the user cut the application when he's dl, because i create a folder wich will be containt the zip, if the application is shut down the folder i've jsut created still there and i'll not be able to detect if i have or not dl the extension game because i'm just checking if the folder bein, i tought about the folder i created can be removed if net down.

Comment: :), Simplest way would be saving a boolean next to the Version if the game is downloaded. But if you want to check corruption you can create a Hash over the folder and check it (All files must be readed for that, could be too slow for each start). To check the download speed from the server, take a look how fast you can download it with the browser. An optimation for that would be using nginx for the static files.

Comment: Great thanks. Are we agree i received data in Octet ? ^^

Comment: Yes, it is binary data. JS uses the type `Buffer` for that. If you want to save it, simply pipe it to an WriteSteam or for Viewing you can use `toString(` nothing or `hex`, `base64`, `binary` `)`

Comment: Great thanks for all @Julian :) It's work like a charm !

Comment: Because we always have more questions, is it possible to make pause / replay while downloading ? ^^

Comment: It is nearly all posible :). To pause (i dont think this useful :)) you should be able to close the underling tcp socket in a way. Or save how many bytes you already have downloaded and start the download at this point the next time

Comment: You right, is not very useful but thanks for the advice, and the last one i dont understand something in auto updating app. Can i auto update the app throw npm directly ? without having my own server running to listen update ? it's the last part and question :) i read about electron -updater but don't understand correctly i think, i have a dead line to saturday to do this ^^ thanks again for all you anwers and advice

Comment: I think you pack all the required modules directly in the App, together with the source code because you don't want to ship npm to the user and install the dependencies in another step. In a setup like this the user wouldn't have npm, and all Updateds come from your server. BUT if your are using npm for the Updates you Push your source there and don't need a server and many of the steps above :) (The downside is less flexibilty)

Comment: Ok but if the users don't have npm it's going to fail.. I have to create my own server with different tutorial i saw, thanks for all :)

Comment: No, if you use electron-updater it will be in you app

Comment: ok, i just take a small server to go throw nuts but can't see how install it ^^ still looking :)